# How to backup all data from specified bucket in couchbase (NOSQL)?

Tags: nosql, backup, couchbase

How am i backup all data and index from one specified bucket in Couch-base (NoSQL)?

Answer (score 1):

Use the cbbackupmgr command line tool. "It backs up and restores bucket data, views creation scripts, index creation scripts, bucket configurations, and so on"

You can find this utility in the bin folder. For example, here it is on Linux:

```
root@15ca2cdf844e:/opt/couchbase/bin# cbbackupmgr
cbbackupmgr [<command>] [<args>]

  backup         Backup a Couchbase cluster
  compact        Compact an incremental backup
  config         Create a new backup configuration
  help           Get extended help for a subcommand
  list           List the archive contents
  merge          Merge incremental backups together
  remove         Delete a backup permanently
  restore        Restore an incremental backup

Optional Flags:

     --version                Prints version information
  -h,--help                   Prints the help message

root@15ca2cdf844e:/opt/couchbase/bin#
```

You can find more information about it in the [Couchbase documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/backup-restore/enterprise-backup-restore.html).

UPDATE: If you are looking to include/exclude specific buckets, you'll need to look at the `cbbackupmgr config`. See [documentation on cbbackupmgr config](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.0/backup-restore/cbbackupmgr-config.html).